# Force square subplots when plotting a colorbar

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, subplot, colorbar

I'm trying to generate two subplots side by side, sharing the `y` axis, with a single colorbar for both.

This is a MWE of my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def rand_data(l, h):
    return np.random.uniform(low=l, high=h, size=(100,))

# Generate data.
x1, x2, y, z = rand_data(0., 1.), rand_data(100., 175.), \
rand_data(150., 200.), rand_data(15., 33.)

fig = plt.figure()
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')

ax0 = plt.subplot(121)
plt.scatter(x1, y, c=z, cmap=cm)

ax1 = plt.subplot(122)
# make these y tick labels invisible
plt.setp(ax1.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.scatter(x2, y, c=z, cmap=cm)

cbar = plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

what this returns is a left subplot slightly larger horizontally than the right one since this last includes the colorbar, see below:

[image]

I've tried using `ax.set_aspect('equal')` but since the `x` axis are not in the same range the result looks awful.

I need both these plots to be displayed squared. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you show how this would work using the MWE I gave above in the form of an answer please?

Comment: To be clear, `aspect` controls the aspect ratio in _data_ units which is frequently far more important.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To expend my comment that one can make 3 plots, plot the `colorbar()` in the 3rd one, the data plots in the 1st and 2nd. This way, if necessary, we are free to do anything we want to the 1st and 2nd plots:

```
def rand_data(l, h):
    return np.random.uniform(low=l, high=h, size=(100,))

# Generate data.
x1, x2, y, z = rand_data(0., 1.), rand_data(100., 175.), \
rand_data(150., 200.), rand_data(15., 33.)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,6))
gs=gridspec.GridSpec(1,3, width_ratios=[4,4,0.2])
ax1 = plt.subplot(gs[0])
ax2 = plt.subplot(gs[1])
ax3 = plt.subplot(gs[2])
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu')
ax1.scatter(x1, y, c=z, cmap=cm)
SC=ax2.scatter(x2, y, c=z, cmap=cm)
plt.setp(ax2.get_yticklabels(), visible=False)
plt.colorbar(SC, cax=ax3)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('temp.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Updated - here is another option without using GridSpec.

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N = 50
x_vals = np.random.rand(N)
y_vals = np.random.rand(N)
z1_vals = np.random.rand(N)
z2_vals = np.random.rand(N)

minimum_z = min(np.min(z1_vals), np.min(z2_vals))
maximum_z = max(np.max(z1_vals), np.max(z2_vals))

fig, axis_array = plt.subplots(1,2, figsize = (20, 10), subplot_kw = {'aspect':1})
ax0 = axis_array[0].scatter(x_vals, y_vals, c = z1_vals, s = 100, cmap = 'rainbow', vmin = minimum_z, vmax = maximum_z)
ax1 = axis_array[1].scatter(x_vals, y_vals, c = z2_vals, s = 100, cmap = 'rainbow', vmin = minimum_z, vmax = maximum_z)

cax = fig.add_axes([0.95, 0.05, 0.02, 0.95]) #this locates the axis that is used for your colorbar. It is scaled 0 - 1. 
fig.colorbar(ax0, cax, orientation = 'vertical') #'ax0' tells it which plot to base the colors on

plt.show()
```

Comment: `cax` is scaled 0 - 1. This doesn't fit the data in the question. How would you go about changing the scale ?

Comment: cax isn't scaled 0-1. The parameters are in % of the total space. The size is specified in the plt.subplots line in the "figsize = (20,10)" kwarg.